# Hosting at australian domain

Tags: dns, hosting, space

Do anybody know an Australian hosting company that offers free space with PHP, MySQL and a free domain like myname.hostingname.com.au? I'm not from AU and I have a problem with information about it.
I care about the ending .com.au.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I am from Australia and have had .com.au addresses.

Web hosting here is insanely expensive, to the point where I don't know anyone providing free hosting.

If all you want is a .com.au domain name then you need to provide an ABN (Australian Business Number) with your registration (which is normally about $75 per year, and does not include hosting. )

I host all of my sites in the USA for a fraction of the cost of hosting here.